# Stumped by a node js ssl server error message "Assertion failed: (wrap->ssl_) != (nullptr), file src\tls_wrap.cc, line 319"

Tags: node.js, ssl

Anyone have a clue as to what causes node js ssl server error "Assertion failed: (wrap->ssl_) != (nullptr), file src\tls_wrap.cc, line 319"?  This is happening on win 7 and linux ubuntu lts. Node 4.4.  Only one google hit which claims the same or a similar error was "fixed" last november, but only for win xp.

Comment: Commenting out "this.socket.end();" makes the error go away.  Also, error only shows up with https server, not with http server. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found an anwser as to why this happens, but I did find a way around it.

Commenting out "this.socket.end();" makes the error go away. Also, error only shows up with https server, not with http server.